# Java get only certain object fields

Tags: java, pojo

I have a POJO which looks like this:

```
public class Task {
    private TaskData taskData;

    String id;
    private int status;
    private int success;
    private int error;
}

class TaskData {
    transient LinkedList<String> list0;
    transient LinkedList<String> list1;
}
```

the lists in `TaskData` can be huge (over 100mb).

When getting all objects from `Map<String, Task> tasksMap = new HashMap()` I don't want `TaskData` fields to be included / be loaded. How can i achieve it?

P.S.
It is not related to serialization.

**Update:**
by "getting all objects" i mean, ex:

```
class SomeClass {
   Map<String, Task> tasksMap = new HashMap()

   SomeClass() {
      //...initialize multiple tasks with huge list0, list1..
      // => add them all
      tasksMap.put("abc0", task);
      tasksMap.put("abc1", task);
      tasksMap.put("abc2", task);
      tasksMap.put("abc3", task);
   }

   Map<String, Task> tasksMap getMap() {
      // when i get all the map's objects, i want the received `Task` objects
      // to not have `TaskData` attribute

      return tasksMap;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you load the Map `tasksMap` ?

Comment: I can think of one solution, implementing your own Map and override put() and remove TaskData while putting into Map.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: What do you mean by "included/loaded"?

Comment: its also unclear what he means by "getting all objects from **Map<String.....**.

Comment: it is not really relevant how does `tasksMap` loaded. (i suppose u mean initialized?). the point is that there are huge lists at the moment when i get all objects from `tasksMap`

Answer (score 1):

Give the field a default value of null, then update the value later, using a setter method.

```
public class Task {
    private TaskData taskData;

    String id;
    private int status;
    private int success;
    private int error;
}

class TaskData {
    transient LinkedList<String> list0 = null;
    transient LinkedList<String> list1 = null;

    public void setList0(LinkedList<String> list){
        list0 = list;
    }

    public void setList1(LinkedList<String> list){
        list1 = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: sure i can do that, but at the moment when i require all `tasksMap`, i'm certain that the lists are huge and not `null`

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach would be to create a shallow copy method, excluding the fields you don't want, and use it when populating you Map, eg :

```
  public Task shallowCopy() {
    Task newTask = new Task();
    newTask.id = id;
    newTask.status = status;
    ...
    return newTask;
  }
```

Comment: still when i request all object from `tasksMap` i suppose all attributes (including huge lists) of those objects are loaded